# Prolog: Next triangular number

Tags: prolog

I am doing an assignment that need to define a relation nexttri(X,Y) such that Y is the least triangular number that is greater than X.

For example

```
?- nexttri(1,3).
true.
?- nexttri(6,Y).
Y = 10.
```

I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to CapelliC's but will accept the case where the triangle number is the smallest not equal to the given number, thus satisfying the OP's requirement *define a relation nexttri(X,Y) such that Y is the least triangular number that is greater than X*:

```
nexttri(X, TriNum) :-
    nexttri(X, 1, 1, TriNum).
nexttri(X, TriCnt, TriInc, TriNum) :-
    NextCnt is TriCnt + 1,
    NextInc is TriInc + NextCnt,
    (   X < TriInc
    ->  TriNum = TriInc
    ;   nexttri(X, NextCnt, NextInc, TriNum)
    ).

?- nexttri(1,1).
false.
?- nexttri(1,3).
true.
?- nexttri(1,4).
false.
?- nexttri(1,6).
false.
?- nexttri(6,Y).
Y = 10.
?- nexttri(9,Y).
Y = 10.
?- nexttri(10,Y).
Y = 15.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually *tried* anything? Showing your code is pretty much *de rigeur* for SO.

Assuming that this is what you mean by "Triangular Number": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Let's start by defining a predicate that will [theoretically] generate a never-ending stream of triangular numbers. Since prolog variables are "write-once" and local, you need to use accumulators a lot. Consequently, a common prolog idiom is the notion of a public interface predicate like this one, that simply invokes the private worker predicate. Something like this:

```
triangular_number(X) :- triangular_number(1,X) .
```

Where we seed the sequence with 1. The worker predicate then computes the triangular number for an equilateral triangle with sides of length *n* and unifies that value with the X. On backtracking then, it increments *n* and recurses. Something like this:

```
triangular_number(P,X) :- P > 0 , sum(P,X) .
triangular_number(P,X) :- P > 0 , P1 is P+1 , triangular_number(P1,X) .
```

As we backtrack into triangular_number/1, X is repeatedly unified with the next triangular number, giving us our never-ending sequence.

The worker predicate here, triangular_number/3 invokes its own worker predicate, sum/2, that computes the series N + N-1 + N-2 ... until N is decremented to zero, so sum(3,X) yields 3+2+1. Something like this:

```
sum(N,X) :- sum(N,0,X) .

sum(0,X,X).
sum(N,T,X) :-
  N > 0 ,
  N1 is N-1 ,
  T1 is T+N ,
  sum(N1,T1,X)
  .
```

Are you starting to notice a pattern here?

Once we can generate triangular numbers, figuring out the next triangular number greater than a specific value is easy:

```
next_triangular_number(N,X) :-
  triangular_number(X) ,
  X > N ,
  ! .
```

It invokes triangular_number/1 to get the first triangular number (1), compares it to the specified bound (N) and either succeeds, or fails, backtracking into triangualar_number/1 only to succeed again with the next triangular number.

Easy! Just let prolog's inference engine do the work.

Whether you want this to be deterministic (by using the cut `!`) or not is up to your problem definition. Should this have just one answer, or should it keep finding solutions on backtracking?

Comment: But when X is not a triangular number, triangular_number(X) will go to infinitely loop. I try to triangular_number(P,X) :- P > 0 , P1 is (P+1) ,P1<X, triangular_number(P1,X) . But when i type in nexttri(6,Y), it gives error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution based on fact that `T(0) = 0` and `T(n) = T(n-1)+n`, with `n` unknown in our case. Just compute the sequence, passing down the hypothetical T(n-1):

```
tri_succ(P, T) :- tri_succ(0, 0, P, T).
tri_succ(N, Tn, L, S) :-
    N1 is N+1,
    Ts is Tn+N1,
    (   L = Tn
    ->  S = Ts
    ;   L > Tn
    ->  tri_succ(N1, Ts, L, S)
    ).
```

test:

```
25 ?- tri_succ(1,T).
T = 3.

26 ?- tri_succ(6,T).
T = 10.

27 ?- tri_succ(7,T).
false.
```